# This isn't a very [logic]al tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logic) tag currently has 5,980 questions. Its description is as follows:

> Logic is about reasoning. This tag is appropriate for such things as logic programming, programming problems involving a logical system, or basic questions about the logical systems used in programming.

In other words, it's wildly ambiguous, and even its creators/describers aren't sure exactly when you should use it.

Also, it seems like the vast majority of the uses for this tag are either covered by other tags, are unnecessary, or are close reasons. For example, many [logic] questions are asking for people to write the basic logic of the program for them (i.e. "gimme teh codez" / "write my algorithm for me" / "gimme teh pseudocodez"), which is a close reason. As another example, [logic-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logic-programming), for example, is already its own tag. As a third example, if you're asking for help writing the logic of your program, then that seems pretty "Meta" to me - in that case, the posters should just tag their questions with their actual topic.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
Nope - the tag Wiki lists 3 different examples of possible uses, and its description of what it actually *means* is beyond vague. I mean, "Logic is about reasoning"? Really?

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
Depends on what you mean by "logic." There are *some* logic questions that are on topic here, but many aren't. If you're asking about "pure" logic (e.g. syllogisms, mathematical logic, etc.), it should probably be on Philosophy or Mathematics SE instead.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
Nope - it's not even clear what the tag is supposed to mean. Not even its describers or creators know what it's supposed to mean.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
No, the tag Wiki is quite clear that this could mean many different things.

Comment: Every time I read any one of  "gimme teh codez", "write my algorithm for me", "gimme teh pseudocodez", or similar, I punch a baby kitten. I just punched three baby kittens because of you. You should be nicer to baby kittens.

Comment: @TinyGiant Fair enough. On a related note, this post seems to be getting downvotes - obviously, I'm not asking about specific votes, but any ideas on why people might disagree with this? I thought that it would be relatively non-controversial.

Comment: @TinyGiant I imagine, with the volume of questions on stack, there isnt an ossue with stray cats in your area then? :p that or you have a couple of really damaged kitties at home

Comment: @Patrice There is an inherent lack of healthy stray kittens in my vicinity. Note that I was not referring to the questions themselves, I'm fine with the questions. The problem I have is with these phrases for describing questions that are as lazy as those using them accuse the askers of being. None of those phrases are actually useful for identifying groups of questions, and they are actively harmful in that they spread the stigma that any question that asks _how_ to do something (as opposed to having a broken code snippet a distinct need for debugging help) are somehow inherently bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm on board with this one and here's why

It's definitely a meta tag. But there is a common context here with the on-topic questions: program logic. Now, some of these border on Code Review, but they still seem to be programming related

- [How can I simplify this set of if statements? (Or, what's making it feel so awkward?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111270/how-can-i-simplify-this-set-of-if-statements-or-whats-making-it-feel-so-awkw)
- [What is the logic to use bitwise operation in generating subsequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098179/what-is-the-logic-to-use-bitwise-operation-in-generating-subsequences)
- [Call shuffle method once and use output multiple times in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021689/call-shuffle-method-once-and-use-output-multiple-times-in-ruby)

Now, I'm normally loathe to link these together, but they're all asking for logic checks, which is still a large part of programming (or at least we hope it is). So we're passing burnination questions 2, 3 and 4.

I think a better excerpt might help (some) here. I would suggest something like this

> Logic refers to the ultimate flow of your code and how you arrive your desired solution. Questions should relate to finding a coding solution (or improving existing coding logic) to a given problem. Please use with an appropriate language tag, a thorough description of your logic, and the relevant code you're working on. General logic questions are off-topic. If you simply need a code review, consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes, improving the tag Wiki like that could help I think - the current tag Wiki is pretty terrible and is very vague as to when you should use the tag and what it's actually about.

Comment: I suppose that an alternative to outright burnination would be to fix the tag Wiki and then clean up the tag. (I suppose that there'd have to be a Meta sanction for that given that it would almost certainly involve significant re-tagging, though). Or, even better, just flat-out rename the tag "program-logic" or something like that.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I agree it needs cleanup. There's a lot of off-topic questions in there

Comment: Yep - cleanup would probably have to wait its turn until after [documentation] (which still has a lot of bad questions left), but it seems like it could be worthwhile.